# Screw/Bolt to mount PCB with spring

Tags: terminology

I hope these exist and someone can tell me what they're called. What I'm looking for is screws to mount a PCB where the top of the screw is normal, then there's a smooth length, then a nut with a spring held in between the top of the screw to the bottom of the bolt so that, for example, if you were to press on the PCB a bit it would move a bit vertically. I'm terrible at drawing things, so I'll try with text:

```
=====   <Top of screw
 |\|    <Spring on smooth part of screw/bolt
 |\|    <Spring on smooth part of screw/bolt
 |\|    <Spring on smooth part of screw/bolt
 ===    <Return to normal threading
 [=]    <Nut
```

Anyone know?

Comment: your drawing describes a `shoulder screw` ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=shoulder+screw&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [captive panel screw](https://catalog.pemnet.com/viewitems/l-screw-screw-head-spring-loaded-flare-mount-pf7mf/screw-screw-head-spring-loaded-flare-mount-unified) appears to be what you're talking about.

[image: Panel screw]

Comment: That looks like it exactly. Thanks!

Comment: But it isn't. A spring top standoff is a permanent mounted PCB standoff that can be quickly removed and reinstalled without loosing any of the parts. It is a totally rigid standoff when installed.

Answer (score 0):

It think you are looking for a spring-loaded heat sink attachment screw. These provide soft compression of a heatsink to a PCB. But you want the spring on the otherside so the mounted board can be pressed down. As far as I know, you can do that. But I'd ask the vendor to confirm it.

[image]